# How to compile a project that uses protobuf in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, protocol-buffers

I want to compile a project that uses protobuf.

> xcode version: 9.3.1 
>  macOS version: 10.13.6

Compile error:

> 'google/protobuf/stubs/common.h' file not found

I read in some sites that I have to install `protobuf`

```
$ brew install protobuf
// installed version: protobuf 3.6.1.3
```

There is a directory in the project, called makefile containing these files:

```
Makefile_ios            compile_ios_protobuf_ssd.sh
build_all_ios_ssd.sh        compile_ios_tensorflow_s.sh
build_tflib_ssd.sh      compile_nsync_ssd.sh
```

when I run these scripts they have error. like

```
$ ./compile_ios_protobuf_ssd.sh
// ./compile_ios_protobuf_ssd.sh: line 25: ./build_helper.subr: No such file or directory

./build_all_ios_ssd.sh
make: tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile_ios: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile_ios'.  Stop.
```

Do I have to install something, or this project has problem?

Comment: Does the project explain how to build it in its README?